# Generate date sequences in a dataframe with variable lengths for each group of duplicated data

Tags: r, date, seq

I have a dataframe and have duplicated rows based on the difference between two dates: Date (date of collection of samples) and hatch (date of birth) using the following code. Difference (basically lifespan in months) ranges from 4-12 months:

```
library(zoo)
test$difference <- 12 * as.numeric(as.yearmon(test$Date) - as.yearmon(test$hatch))

test$difference <- ceiling(test$difference)
test2 <- test[rep(row.names(test), test$difference),]
```

I need to create a sequence for each specimen (each of which has a unique serial number, sn) starting from the hatching date, increasing in 1 month increments and with the length out equal to the value in the differences column. I tried a loop but I could not work out how to phrase it as I'm quite new to R.

At the moment the dates are in the format %Y-%m-%d but I'm only interested in the month and year groupings.

Any insights would be really useful :)

```
    structure(list(Sex = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("F", "J", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Maturity = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), XLength = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5), Weight = c(44.1, 
    44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 44.1, 73.6, 73.6, 
    73.6, 73.6, 73.6, 73.6), Ringcount = c(232L, 232L, 232L, 
    232L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 225L, 225L, 225L, 225L, 
    225L, 225L), Date = structure(c(10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 
    10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 10480, 
    10480, 10480), class = "Date"), hatch = structure(c(10248, 
    10248, 10248, 10248, 10248, 10248, 10248, 10248, 10248, 10255, 
    10255, 10255, 10255, 10255, 10255), class = "Date"), sn = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), difference = c(9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), .Names = c("Sex", 
"Maturity", "XLength", "Weight", "Ringcount", "Date", "hatch", 
"sn", "difference"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: did you `dput` the file correctly? I get an error while loading it

Comment: @DJV Judging from the `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x03f424a0>`, it's probably a `dput` from a data.table which _doesn't_ work. OP please convert your data.table back to a data.frame and post the `dput` again.

Comment: @useR I did suspected the `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x03f424a0>` but I didn't know what it meant. Good to know and thank you.

Comment: Guys, you can simply remove `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x03f424a0>` part and it should work.

Comment: @MKR it would "successfully" load the data as a `data.table` without the selfref pointer, but when you do anything that changes the dt by reference, you get an error because you removed the pointer (Try `dt[, count := 1]`). A better way would be to convert to data.frame and have `dput` that instead..

Comment: @useR May be you can try `setDF()` so convert it back to `data.frame`.

Comment: @MKR I can, but (along with deleting the pointer) that's extra work for the reader that shouldn't be there in the first place. Nowhere in the question did OP mention that `data.table` is required, so a reader would need to know to load `data.table`, delete the pointer, and `setDF` just to read in the data. Why not keep the question as simple as possible by providing `dput(df)`?

Comment: @useR I can understand that OP should correct it. But people can work on answer and then guide OP to correct mistake. Probably, OP is a new user anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming you want to add a new column with the dates, using `test` we can write the following.  It uses no packages.

```
Seq <- function(h) seq(h[1], length = length(h), by = "month")
transform(test, dates = ave(hatch, sn, FUN = Seq))
```

giving:

```
   Sex Maturity XLength Weight Ringcount       Date      hatch sn difference      dates
1    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-01-22
2    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-02-22
3    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-03-22
4    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-04-22
5    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-05-22
6    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-06-22
7    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-07-22
8    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-08-22
9    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 1998-09-22
10   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-01-29
11   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-03-01
12   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-03-29
13   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-04-29
14   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-05-29
15   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 1998-06-29
```

**2)** Alternately if you just want year and month use `yearmon` class from zoo.

```
library(zoo)

Seq_ym <- function(h) h[1] + (seq_along(h) - 1) / 12
transform(test, dates = ave(as.yearmon(hatch), sn, FUN = Seq_ym))
```

giving:

```
   Sex Maturity XLength Weight Ringcount       Date      hatch sn difference    dates
1    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Jan 1998
2    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Feb 1998
3    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Mar 1998
4    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Apr 1998
5    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 May 1998
6    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Jun 1998
7    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Jul 1998
8    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Aug 1998
9    M        5    12.0   44.1       232 1998-09-11 1998-01-22  1          9 Sep 1998
10   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 Jan 1998
11   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 Feb 1998
12   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 Mar 1998
13   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 Apr 1998
14   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 May 1998
15   M        5    16.5   73.6       225 1998-09-11 1998-01-29  2          9 Jun 1998
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry this is my first question so I wasn't sure on how to use dput(), i'll make an edit